# 1. Print all shipment details that are sent by Phillip? 2.Print all shipments which are in 'In-Transit' status

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**This is the given dictionary**

```
dict1= {101: {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '14-03-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-03-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 6', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 198}, 102: {'Sender': 'Romesh', 'Receiver': 'Phillip', 'Start date': '18-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '09-07-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 2', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 275}, 103: {'Sender': 'Omega lll', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '01-12-2020', 'Delivery date': 'Null', 'Sender location': 'Area 5', 'Receiver location': 'Area 1', 'Delivery status': 'In Transit', 'Shipping cost': 200}, 104: {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'John', 'Start date': '23-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-06-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 314}, 105: {'Sender': 'Ramya', 'Receiver': 'Romesh', 'Start date': '29-08-2020', 'Delivery date': '10-09-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 5', 'Receiver location': 'Area 3', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 275}, 106: {'Sender': 'John', 'Receiver': 'Omega lll', 'Start date': '28-06-2020', 'Delivery date': 'Null', 'Sender location': 'Area 3', 'Receiver location': 'Area 1', 'Delivery status': 'In Transit', 'Shipping cost': 270}}
```

Can someone help me out with this problem

Answer (score -1):

Let's select only the dictionary values where Sender is Phillip.

```py
# dict1.values() gives an array of the values of dict1
# filter takes a function that determines which values to keep (lambda) and the dict1.values() array
#    in this case it only accepts values with 'Sender' == 'Phillip'
# list converts filter's output into a normal list
dict1 = {101: {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '14-03-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-03-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 6', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 198}, 102: {'Sender': 'Romesh', 'Receiver': 'Phillip', 'Start date': '18-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '09-07-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 2', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 275}, 103: {'Sender': 'Omega lll', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '01-12-2020', 'Delivery date': 'Null', 'Sender location': 'Area 5', 'Receiver location': 'Area 1', 'Delivery status': 'In Transit', 'Shipping cost': 200}, 104: {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'John', 'Start date': '23-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-06-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 314}, 105: {'Sender': 'Ramya', 'Receiver': 'Romesh', 'Start date': '29-08-2020', 'Delivery date': '10-09-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 5', 'Receiver location': 'Area 3', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 275}, 106: {'Sender': 'John', 'Receiver': 'Omega lll', 'Start date': '28-06-2020', 'Delivery date': 'Null', 'Sender location': 'Area 3', 'Receiver location': 'Area 1', 'Delivery status': 'In Transit', 'Shipping cost': 270}}
phillips = list(filter(lambda value: value['Sender'] == 'Phillip',
                       dict1.values()))
print(phillips)
```

The result is

```sh
[{'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '14-03-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-03-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 6', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 198}, {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'John', 'Start date': '23-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-06-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 314}]
```

You can use the exact same strategy `filter(lambda x: _____, dict1.values())` to find the items that are in-transit.

Comment: The code is correct (I tested python2.7 and 3.9 both work) try copying and pasting it into the python3 repl. Be sure you include the dict1 definition. Is it possible you're running it on a different dictionary where no entry has the sender Phillip?

Comment: Print all shipments which are delivered after 15 days of courier start date or not yet been delivered ? and Print all shipments which are delivered within 7 days of courier Start date?    How print these ?